# Data Integrity and authenticity check

Tags: system-installation, iso

I am trying to shift from 12.04 LTS to 16.04.3 LTS desktop amd64 through a fresh install (iso file download on a DVD).

In the process, is it necessary to verify the Ubuntu download prior to installation - its a bit complicated for me! ;)

Secondly, is there a way to know whether my computer hardware is compatible with 16.04.3?

Thanks for the reply.

Comment: It is not necessary but a good idea to check that the downloaded file was transferred correctly. You can also check afterwards from the boot menu according to this link, https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2196858&p=13511608#post13511608 ; Try live (booted from the DVD) and you will find out if/how it works ;-) Please come back with details (in your original question), if there are problems.

Comment: And https://askubuntu.com/questions/986878/will-my-device-work-with-ubuntu

Answer (score 1):

> In the process, is it necessary to verify the Ubuntu download prior to installation - its a bit complicated for me! ;)

If you are worried about the download not being correct: yes. It is very [very simple](https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-how-to-verify-ubuntu#0).

> Secondly, is there a way to know whether my computer hardware is compatible with 16.04.3?

If the live session starts without issues, set up wireless. You can then play around with your system and if it all seems to work generally the normal install works too. Besides that: if 12.04 works 16.04 is likely to work too unless you got really really old hardware.

You can also write down all your hardware specs and have a look on the internet. Generally the 2 components that need attention are the video card and the network card. If the video card is AMD or nVidia you should be fine. If the network card is intel it will be fine. Broadcom can be a challenge.

Comment: Ubuntu
Release 12.04 (precise) 32-bit
Kernel Linux 3.2.0-126-generic-pae
GNOME 3.4.2

Hardware
Memory 3.9 GiB
Processor: Pentium(R) Dual-Core CPU E5200 @ 2.50GHz x 2

System Status
Available disk space: 347.3 GiB

You think its good for 16.04.3?

Comment: Try and find out. What you think is "good" I might itch to throw down from the 6th floor ;-)